# Debian wheezy, update repository

Tags: debian

I'm working with a `Debian GNU/Linux 7.5 (wheezy)`

When I check the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` The file has this line:

```
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

I tried to replaces for another repo line, but each time I replace it and run the command `apt-get update` after a while, I get:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*EDIT: You maybe able to follow the advice in [this linuxquestions thread](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/failed-to-verify-lines-in-etc-apt-sources-list-741761/) and uncomment the relevant entries in your `sources.list` and try to run `apt update`.*

Debian 7 reached [EOL](https://www.debian.org/News/2018/20180601) as of May 31, 2018. Those repositories are no longer active. You can still receive support for Wheezy but it is going to be a lot less painful and expensive on your part to make moves to migrate to Jessie or even Stretch.

On the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Wheezy) there is advice on what to do now that Debian Wheezy is EOL. You may also want to check out [this entry](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using) to get more information on what to do.

If you are upgrading to Jessie, your `sources.list` needs to changed to the following:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Then run `apt update`, `apt install apt -t jessie`, `apt upgrade`, and finally `apt-get dist-upgrade` to update and upgrade to Jessie.

If you absolutely need to stay on Wheezy and cannot change to Jessie, either due to [issues outlined here](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/release-notes/ch-information.en.html) or because of some other limitations on your environment then you may need to change over to the archive mirrors or look into paid ELTS support.

Archive mirrors will look something like [this](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive):

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Comment: `apt dist-upgrade` faild for me with an unmet dependency on plymouth. An `apt-get install udev plymouth` followed by a `apt dist-upgrade` solved it for me.

Comment: Note, latest release is now `buster`. I managed to dist-upgrade all the way from wheezy to this (I went release by release so it was quite long winded) but it worked fine because Debian is so amazing.

Comment: I want to add one more note. Most probably after changins sources.list and running **apt-get update** you will get error *There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551* Which should be solved like this **sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551** (don't forget to change your hash). Original answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/766883/there-is-no-public-key-available-for-the-following-key-ids-1397bc53640db551

Answer (score 1):

```
https://www.debian.org/security/
```

has some information on it, about updating it to (there must be "main" at the end):

```
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
```

Comment: This does not work - wheezy is too old for Debian security